# Is it possible to create a temporary ABAddressBook Database in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

I would create a temporary ABAddressBook Database in iOS which doesn't interact with the "normal" ABAdressBook database. I would just like to do it to use the `ABPersonViewController`. My contacts data is stored in an sqlite.swift database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been playing around the idea as well, but it is not possible.

As soon as you create address instance, it will be displayed in the "normal" address book as well.

Comment: "As soon as you create address instance, it will be displayed in the "normal" address book as well" True but nothing stops you from immediately deleting it from the normal address book.

Comment: ok, but now i have a very simple question to you ... do you know what UIElements are used to display the telephone number or other contacts data in the ABPersonViewController?

Comment: @PhilippJanuskovecz Yes, and so do you. Just use View Debugging to examine them.